# Upgrading nginx on Centos 6.8

Tags: nginx, centos, yum

I'm trying to update Nginx on Centos 6.8. I tried

```
sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo
```

and then changing the nginx.repo to

```
[nginx]
name=nginx repo
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/centos/$releasever/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

and then ran:

```
sudo yum update && sudo yum install nginx
```

But when I check the version with `nginx -v`, it's still version 1.9.2.
I also tried quitting and reloading, but neither did anything. 
Also tried:

```
cd /opt
wget http://nginx.org/packages/centos/6/x86_64/RPMS/nginx-1.10.1-1.el6.ngx.x86_64.rpm
yum update nginx-1.10.1-1.el6.ngx.x86_64.rpm
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's more of SuperUser question than StackOverflow one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the latest epel-release rpm from http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/

Install epel-release rpm:

```
# rpm -Uvh epel-release*rpm
```

Install nginx rpm package:

```
# yum --enablerepo=epel-testing install nginx
```

Comment: Just tried this and I get  
`Package nginx-1.11.3-1.el6.ngx.x86_64 already installed and latest version`
Nothing to do
But when I do `nginx -v` it tells me: `nginx version: nginx/1.9.2`

Comment: @Soubriquet What's the output for `which nginx` ?

Comment: `/usr/local/sbin/nginx` for `which nginx`

Comment: @Soubriquet What's the output for `/usr/sbin/nginx -v` ?

Comment: and `nginx version: nginx/1.11.3` for  `/usr/sbin/nginx -v`

Comment: @Soubriquet There you go. You have a manually installed `nginx` in `/usr/local`

Comment: Yeah. Should I just delete that one?

Comment: @Soubriquet You should uninstall it. Or leave it as it is, and use `/ust/sbin/nginx` instead.

Comment: How do I change the `nginx` in `/usr/sbin/nginx` to use my `nginx.conf` file from 1.9.2?

Comment: @Soubriquet Where you nginx.conf located?

Comment: It's in `/usr/local/nginx/conf`

Comment: @Soubriquet copy it to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and if you have custom configs, copy them to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`

Comment: Ok, so I copied the files over and when I use the command `nginx` in `/etc/nginx` I get `nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)`
`nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)`
`nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()`

Comment: @Soubriquet You have to stop the already running nginx instance first.

Comment: Ok. I killed the process of the old one, and tried `nginx` in `/etc/nginx` again, but it doesn't seem to be able to find my server. I can see nginx running with `netstat -antp`

Comment: @Soubriquet Find out on which port it is running.

Comment: `nginx` is running on `8080`

Comment: Sorry, just realized it should be on port `80` instead. Dumb mistake. Thanks for all the help btw!